# Linux based QGIS File Geodatabase access

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, linux

I have looked for a "recipe" to get QGIS to read FGDB but cannot find anything. I'm fairly new to Linux and need a step by step procedure or somewhere to find the steps. I'm running QGIS 2.14.3 Essen on Mint.